# dbms_aq package methods are not accessible

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-aq

I am bangin my head on this for a day now. I am not able to invoke dbms_aq package methods.
this is my code.

```
PROCEDURE P_ENQUEUE(
  QUEUE_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
  PAYLOAD IN TYPE_RECORD
) AS 
 enqueue_options SYS.dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
 message_properties SYS.dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
 message_handle RAW(16);
 po_t SYS.dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
BEGIN

SYS.dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table(QUEUE_NAME, NULL, po_t);
SYS.dbms_aq.enqueue(queue_name => QUEUE_NAME,
    enqueue_options => enqueue_options,
    message_properties => message_properties,
    payload => PAYLOAD,
    msgid => message_handle);
END;
```

I am trying to call this procedure from a trigger and i checked this is getting called properly. But not able to call dbms_aqadm and dbms_aq procedures.

this works fine when not called from a trigger.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the same user executing the packages outside the trigger as the one causing the trigger to fire?  Could be execute permission issue on the packages.

Comment: What version of Oracle? What are the symptoms of the problem?

Comment: version is 11g and user is same

Comment: Its not actually a trigger but a DCN callback procedure

Comment: PLease show the EXACT error messages.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages on console

Comment: The purge_queue_table procedure creates a trace file in the udump directory. Was that created?  Do you know for a fact the trigger fired?

Comment: yes i added some insert table line in this procedure ad it is getting called and no such file is getting created